# DataGrid selected item changed more quickly than data loads from DB

Tags: wpf, datagrid

We have the following WPF : a datagrid with row detail template. Selected line on this grid (customer selection) is handled to trigger two queries to retrieve address and contacts data, then row detail template show these data in two tabs, each with a datagrid. All the magic is done with binding, subgrids bind to properties of main Customer object, which we have as an IObservableCollection.

The bug happens when using “move down” arrow on keyboard, selected index changes fast, so fast than queries result “come back late” to interface, thus data is incoherent to what is shown and data update cannot perform. We have an exception. So my question is : how to prevent this in a proper manner ?

Should we have a try-catch the right kind of obscure exception then do nothing (loose data that cannot be applied to interface) ?
We don’t want to wait for data to come back, if user scrolls very quickly, customer selected line should go down and no matter details aren’t shown.
Maybe we should have a delay before selected item details are retrieved ? Thus no query if selected item changes before end of delay ?

Thank you for your ideas.

Gists for code:
Xaml : https://gist.github.com/Xarkam/3b89eb614124bb2f2307
Selected index changed handling : https://gist.github.com/Xarkam/cf28844ce05fd4984807

**Edit 10th of July :**
I have modified the main datagrid items definition as in following gist : (add `https://` prefix, I don't have enough reputation to add more links, sorry) gist.github.com/postb99/d3be79f0ef2544d685f9 (inspired from stackoverflow.com/questions/13374957/datagrid-throws-invalidoperationexception-by-scrolling and proposed answer) but problem still persists...

Answer (score 0):

We've solved it, if I remember well we didn't have observable collections for every collection of objects to display.